# How do I create a side menu navigation bar that opens items to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to copy a website for practice(new to html, css, and javascript) So I created a navigation bar on the left(like on the link provided for the food items) and when you click on it, it is supposed to pop up the items they have to the right of the navigation bar. I am not sure what that is called and how to do that. Is there a tutorial that you guys know that teaches me how to do that. I only found things like drop down menu, etc. Here is the website I am trying to copy
http://order.carsidetogo.com/menu/applebees-fairfax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called tabs, they can be horizental(top/bottom) or vertical(left/right), you can take a look at this w3schools tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp .